# Memory consumption in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, swap, memory-usage

Any hint on why this memory consumption and what can I do to solve it?
Causes my laptop to frequently freeze

[image]

Comment: You can run `inxi -t m10` from a terminal to show you the Top 10 biggest memory using applications.  You can change the m10 to any number you want, like m20 for Top 20, etc.

Comment: Have a look at what processes are using most of the memory. For example, start a terminal and run `top` then press shift+M to sort by %memory.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `swapon -s` and `sudo lshw -C memory`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.